# What is a simple function in Vue.js that I can use to validate an input's format?

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js

In Vue.js I have this:

```
<template>
    <button @click="sendMail(); $emit('close')">Send</button>
</template>
<script>
    methods: {
        sendMail () {
            axios.post('/mail', {email: this.email});
            this.$notify.make('Sent!', 'success');
        },
        invalidEmail () {
            this.$notify.make('Invalid email format!', 'failure'):
        }
    }
</script>
```

How will I be able to trigger `invalidEmail()` when the email input is not of valid format?

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. Do you simply want a way to check if some email is invalid before calling sendMail?

Comment: You can pass `$event` to your event listener `sendMail($event)`, get as a function argument `methods: { sendMail(event) ...` and check if `event.target.value` is valid.

Comment: Yes, and I still don't have a way to check if the input is valid. @Cobaltway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to check for email validity.

Source of the regex: http://emailregex.com/

```
<template>
    <button @click="sendMail(); $emit('close')">Send</button>
</template>
<script>
    // Here is the regex to test if an email is valid
    const mailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    module.exports = {
        // [...]
        methods: {
            sendMail () {
                // If this.email is not a valid email, abort by return and call this.invalidEmail
                if (!mailRegex.test(this.email)) return this.invalidEmail();

                axios.post('/mail', {email: this.email});
                this.$notify.make('Sent!', 'success');
            },
            invalidEmail () {
                this.$notify.make('Invalid email format!', 'failure'):
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```